Is a question asking for a ranked list of Elden Ring remembrances on topic?
Here’s the question body:

What are the best remembrances in Elden Ring?
This could also be interpreted as, what gives the best stuff.
Rank the remembrances based on how good the gear they give is, how
viable they are around the time you’d get them (and what other stuff
you could be expected to have at that point), and how well they fit a
Str/Dex build that focuses on “assassin attacks” (fast and strong)
that is not a spellcaster.

If it’s not, how could it be edited to make it on topic?

You may benefit from reading about The X/Y problem - i.e. instead of asking for an ordered list/rank of every remembrance (X), ask about your actual problem (Y) - which remembrances pair well with a Str/Dex Assassin build.

Asking for a list of things to be ranked on "goodness" is inherently opinion-based, and the question should be closed with that reason.
One possible way to salvage it would be to ask a mostly objective question without ranking, based on the last part that narrows it down:

Which remembrance weapons scale with strength and/or dexterity and have a fast attack speed?


There is however, good opinion based questions. Asking which weapons or w/e work best for a certain build is subjective, but it is a good subjective question that can be answered. Asking overall best weapon in general is a bad subjective question though.

@murgatroid99 Would asking what weapons scale best with stats be subjective? There is some in game data that shows the scaling via letters (S is best, don’t know what’s worst) that would likely make it objective.

That would be pretty much objective; answers just have to account for the different scaling of each stat, and how that makes the ordering depend on the player's stats. However, that's probably unnecessary because there are only about 4 weapons that meet those criteria anyway; once you narrow it down that far you can examine them yourself and make your own determination.
